# send data with Ajax to Spring Controller

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a page JSP where I want to send data using AJAX to My Controller . but it doesn t work .I got error in the console : Error 404 .

My Controller :

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/sendemail",method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public void sendemail(){


    }
   @RequestMapping(value="/sendemail",method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public void sendemailget(){

}
```

in my page jsp :

```
<div class="row col-xs-10 col-md-6 form-group">
<!--              <textarea rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea> -->
             <springform:textarea path="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="5"/>
           </div>
            <div class="row">
               <span class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <a class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right" id="sendemail">Envoyer email</a>
               </span>
            </div>


<script>
$('#sendemail').click( function(){
   $.ajax({
          url:'/sendemail',
          type:"Post",
          dataType:'json',
          contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success : function() {
                     console.log("SUCCESS: ");

                     },
           error : function() {
                     console.log("ERROR: ");

                     },
           done : function() {
                     console.log("DONE");

                     }

       });


     });
</script>
```

I got this error in the browser console :

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8989/sendemail
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 
Remote Address:[::1]:8989
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Content-Language:fr-FR
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 14 Sep 2017 04:33:30 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=B40E408BBC4209D1CECC9336B3AD3EC1
Host:localhost:8989
Origin:http://localhost:8989
Referer:http://localhost:8989/detail/1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

like you see I didn t send any thing to my controller , I just wanted to start with empty to see if the request reach the controller , but it didn t, thank you.

Comment: Have you annotated `@RestController` or `@Controller`and any mapping given at controller level?

Comment: yes My controller is annotated @Controller and  no mapping at controller level.